# I Recently Installed Ubuntu Desktop GUI Over My Ubuntu Server Install and I Broke Some Bash Commands

Tags: server, bash

I have been running a virtualbox of Ubuntu Server for web development and have been getting along quite nicely. I decided to install Ubuntu Desktop via "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" so I can use Sublime Text until I get better with Vim. I have been SSH into my VM from PuTTY, and had my .bashrc set up how I liked it. Now that I have the GUI installed though, many bash commands aren't working and my shell settings are different.

For example, 'ls' now gives me this error:

```
ls: cannot access .color=auto: No such file or directory
```

I have verified that I am using /bin/bash via:

```
echo $SHELL
```

I believe it has something to do with using a non-login version of bash vs a login version over SSH, but I have tried sourcing the .bashrc and .profile to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This smells like a problem with your aliases. You probably have something like

```
alias ls="ls -h .color=auto"
```

This is what I have:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

After changing you need to reload the desktop!